# Android UI behaves differently with different display hardware

Tags: android, android-drawable, display, android-wallpaper, surfaceflinger

My android device behaves in a strange manner when I connect a **1366 X 768** lvds display. The UI is different from what I was getting with HDMI connected. I'm getting a different home screen with some other wallpaper and more than that the navigation keys at the bottom are missing.

It looks like based on the hardware display configuration the UI is configured.

Is there a way to override this behaviour? Please suggest some ways to tackle this..

> Android Version : Lollipop 5.0.1

Comment: Is this a device you've bought and you're trying to make work with external displays, or are you doing the system integration for the device?

Comment: it is a development board based on snapdragon 400 series (IFC 6309, APQ8016). display used is dsi to lvds with a resolution 1366X768. we tried the same on a 1080p hdmi (dsi to hdmi) display, where we are getting proper UI.

Comment: Problem solved .. :-) It was behaving differently due to a hard coded display density value..

Comment: If you've solved your problem, post an answer saying what you did to debug and fix it, and mark it as solved (the check mark on the left). That way, other users can see your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was due to a hard coded display density parameter. It was hard coded to 240. Issue is resolved when the density value is changed to 160.

$adb shell "echo qemu.sf.lcd_density=160 >> /system/build.prop"

Thanks,
Arjun.